# is it possible to colorize grayscaled image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a grayscaled image (filled shape with some gradient decoration) as an ImageResource in my ImageView. Is it possible to somehow apply color to that image? Maybe with the help of setColorFilter? I've read about PorterDuff.Mode, but could not figure out how to use it properly.
I'd be grateful for any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a single color easily to your ImageView with the following code:

```
PorterDuffColorFilter mColorFilter = 
        new PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN)

imageView.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
```

You can change the PorterDuff mode to your requirements.

Comment: If there's any transparent pixels in your image it might be a better idea to use PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY instead